# Не работает отправка письма

Tags: php, wordpress

После переноса сайта на новый хостинг перестал исполняться скрипт отправки почты, пишет ошибка 404 файл не найден. Пути 20 раз проверил, при открытии в браузере файла по ссылке пишет "No input file specified".
В чем может быть проблема?
Еще заметил что не работают ссылки именно в скриптах, все иконки на сайте подключенные скриптами не загружаются.

```
<form id="callback_form">
    <input name="callback_name" type="text">
    <input name="callback_phone" type="text">
    <button>Мы вам позвоним</button>
</form>

<?php
  $recepient = "test@yandex.ru";
  $siteName = "test.ru";

  $name = trim($_POST["callback_name"]);
  $phone = trim($_POST["callback_phone"]);
  $message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $phone";

  $pagetitle = "Заявка с сайта \"$siteName\"";
  mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
?>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  $('#callback_form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/callback-mail.php",   
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      $(this).find('input').val('');
      $('#callback_form').trigger('reset');
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Потому что а) переносить нужно [правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress) и б) использовать плагины обратных форм, а не этот дырявый код

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 быстрых варианта решения:

1. Использовать стандартную функцию [wp_mail()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_mail)
2. Использовать плагин "[Contact Form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)"

Если искать корень проблемы, то она может возникнуть из-за разных версий php, из-за прав доступа к директориям, из-за разных настроек apache.